# Large database needs reconciling

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very large database with a unique form_id key and a lot of other information. Some how some of the evaluations got put into the database with a space in front of the supervisor_name (i.e. 'test test' vs ' test test') so it is messing up search results of the same supervisor into two categories (still investigating how my form allowed this). What would be the MYSQL to update these thousands of forms. I know I would need to start with pulling all of the form ids then go through that loop but what would the UPDATE code look like and what would only get rid of the initial space and not delete any letters of anyones name?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET supervisor_name = SUBSTRING(supervisor_name, 2)
WHERE supervisor_name LIKE ' %'
```

or if you are paranoid about relying on `LIKE` then you could also explicitly check the first character from the `supervisor_name` column:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET supervisor_name = SUBSTRING(supervisor_name, 2)
WHERE SUBSTRING(supervisor_name, 1, 1) = ' '
```